# Why is my string containing a URL breaking my script?

Tags: php, twitter

Using twitterauth to try to post status updates. This is my code (which returns a 403 error from twitter when I try to post it):

```
$fact = "This is a status update. http://onth.is/iss" ;
$parameters = array('status' => $fact);
```

However, if I do this:

```
$parameters = array('status' => "This is a status update. http://onth.is/iss");
```

It post perfectly fine. I know it has something to do wit the URL, because if I remove it from the first code it works.

Any tips? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have to assume there's a copy/paste error here, since the version that "works" is missing a closing paren?

Comment: Is the second correct without the closing paren, or is that a typo?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that code. Except for the missing paranthesis.

Comment: That's a typo. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Try a more complete pastie; something's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the [twitteroath](http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) library then I don't see anything wrong with your code. However, you can speed things up a little bit by doing:

```
$parameters["status"] = "This is a status update. http://onth.is/iss";
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed my one line to what you suggested. It looks like it's working better. I'm wondering if I just wasn't running into some rate limits on Twitter's API while I was testing it.

Answer (score 0):

The two statements are identical, except that the latter will create a syntax error :)

My guess would be that you need to [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/urlencode) the string before sending it to Twitter, but not knowing the library you are using, I can't say for sure.